# How to use a counter as an argument in functions?

Tags: vba, excel

a standard loop in Excel VBA goes like this:

```
dim i as integer
for i = 1 to 100 
<do program>
next
end sub
```

Now, my question is: how can I use the counter, i, as an argument in the program?

example:

```
dim i as integer
for i = 1 to 100 

If Range("Ci") = 0 Then
Rows("i:i").Select
Rows.Delete

next
end sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
 dim i as integer
 for i = 1 to 100 

      If Range("C" & i) = 0 Then
           Rows(i & ":" & i).Select
           Rows.Delete
      end if
 next
 end sub
```

The `&` is the concatenation operator which is used to add a string onto another string.

Now `i` is obviously a number in the above example, but VBScript is smart enough to know what you're doing and, for example, just stick `"C"` and the current value of `i` together.

Comment: A cautionary note: If you're really deleting rows, count backwards like *For i = 100 to 1 Step -1*.  Otherwise you'll get results you may not expect.

Comment: @Dick ... or use a Do..Loop construct and do not advance i on delete, because row(i+1) will take the place of row i once row(i) is deleted.

Comment: Thanks for these tips guys. The row deletion was just a quick example; the actual program does some formatting to the Excel sheet.